# Raising an exception in a custom ufunc in a NumPy ndarray subclass

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ufunc

I'm implementing a NumPy ndarray subclass with a custom `equal()` universal function.

This is a distilled example where the custom `equal()` ufunc just calls the original:

```
class MyArray(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, data):
        return np.array(data).view(MyArray)

    def __array_ufunc__(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs):
        inputs = [i.view(np.ndarray) for i in inputs]
        if ufunc == np.equal and method == "__call__":
            return self._custom_equal(*inputs, **kwargs)
        return super().__array_ufunc__(ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def _custom_equal(a, b, **kwargs):
        return np.equal(a, b, **kwargs)
```

This works:

```
>>> a = MyArray([(1,2,3), (4,5,6)])
>>> b = MyArray([(1,2,3), (4,5,6)])
>>> a == b
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
```

But when the arrays have different shapes a `DeprecationWarning` is issued and the fuction returns `False`:

```
>>> c = MyArray([(1,2,3,4,5,6)])
>>> a == c
DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  a == c
False
```

When `_custom_equal()` is updated:

```
    @staticmethod
    def _custom_equal(a, b, **kwargs):
        try:
            eq = np.equal(a, b, **kwargs)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            raise
        return eq
```

It can be seen that the exception is raised, then the comparison is retried:

```
>>> a == c
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (1,6) 
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,6) (2,3) 
False
DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  a == c
```

Comparing array shapes and explicitly raising an exception produces the same result.

Is there a way to have the exception raised instead of getting a `False` result value?

Comment: I believe that no exception is raised in your version of Numpy, it is just a `DeprecationWarning`. If you try to update Numpy, you will get an error and `False` will not be returned (I just tried with '1.26.3')

Comment: Yes, an exception is raised, as it can be seen in the last example. Explicitly raising any exception in _custom_equal() produces the DeprecationWarning and returns False.

Comment: What is your version of Numpy ?

Comment: Numpy version 1.24.4

Comment: Numpy version 1.26.3 solves the problem, raising
`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (1,6)`.
But I'd like to know how to make it work also with other recent versions.

Comment: It may be possible to use the `warnings` module to turn the `DeprecationWarning` into an error.

Comment: True, but the exception is the warning itself, and the real cause is lost. Not nice for library users. Well. the original exception can be found in the stack trace, but then it's necessary to create a context manager that catches the warning, inspects the stack and raises a new exception with the real cause. I'll probably implement this, but I'd be happier if I could avoid the warning altogether.